# Image of morphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

Suppose I have a morphism of sheaves $f : E^{\oplus4} \to I_p$ on $X$ a degree $3$ Fano threefold, where $E$ is a rank $2$ vector bundle on $X$ and $I_p$ is an ideal sheaf of a point $p \in X$. I'm interested in knowing the image of $f$.

For each of the direct summands, I have a morphism $f_i : E \to I_p$ and I know that the image of such a morphism is $I_{D_i}$ where $D_i$ is a degree $5$ curve containing $p$. Is there a way in which I can use this information to find the image of $f$? I'm hoping that this  makes $\mathrm{im}(f) = I_p$, but I'm not sure if this is true, and if so, how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the image you can replace $I_p$ by $\mathcal{O}_X$ and the copies of $E$ by $I_{D_i}$. Then your question becomes: what is the image of
$$
I_{D_1} \oplus I_{D_2} \oplus I_{D_3} \oplus I_{D_4} \to \mathcal{O}_X.
$$
The image of the direct sum of ideal sheaves is, of course, the sum of the corresponding ideals, i.e., the ideal of the corresponding intersection of schemes. So, it proves that the image you are interested in is $I_Z$, where
$$
Z = D_1 \cap D_2 \cap D_3 \cap D_4.
$$
In particular, if you want to prove it is $I_p$, you need to check that the scheme-theoretic intersection of your quintic curves is the point $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!